# How can I get the Terraform module name programmatically?

Tags: terraform, hcl

I have defined the following Terraform module:

```
module "lambda" {
  source                = "../lambda"
  region                =  "us-west-1"
  account               = "${var.account}"
}
```

How can I take advantage from the module name to set the `source` parameter with an interpolation? I wish something like:

```
module "lambda" {
  source                = "../${this.name}"
  region                =  "us-west-1"
  account               = "${var.account}"
}
```

Comment: I don't believe you can - the name you give it becomes an implicit "variable" you can use elsewhere in your scripts, so if your module here had an output of `xyz`, you would reference it via `module.lambda.xyz` - I don't think there's another layer of interpolation available above this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think is not possible. There's a [`self`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#attributes-of-your-own-resource) that allows you to reference attributes within your resource, but the identifier is not an attribute. Also, `self` is only allowed within provisioners.

I guess the only way to accomplish what you want is templating the `.tf` files, like:

```
module {{ my-module}} {
  source                = "../{{ my-module }}"
  region                =  "us-west-1"
  account               = "${var.account}"
```

but you should render the templates before `terraform init`. It's straightforward to setup in a CI pipeline, but I find it cumbersome when working locally.

Answer (score 8):

```
locals {
  module = basename(abspath(path.module))
}

{
...
  some-id = local.module
...
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: This looks like a useful piece of code, but it only works inside the module. The original question is asking how to access the name within the module block.

Comment: not the name the module is referenced with. (see "lambda" in question)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, self is not available in modules so you would have to pass the name explicitly.

I'm adding another example since the above examples don't differentiate between the name of the module and the instances that call it.

Here is the "router" module:

```
variable "name" {
  description = "The name of this instance"
  type = string
}

locals {
  module = basename(path.module)
}

output "message" {
  value = "${var.name} is a instance of ${local.module}"
}
```

Here is a root module that instantiates two routers by calling the router module twice:

```
terraform {
}

module "r1" {
  source = "../modules/router"
  name = "r1"  # must match module label since there is no "self"
}

module "r2" {
  source = "../modules/router"
  name = "r2"  # must match module label since there is no "self"
}

locals {
  module_messages = [
    module.r1.message,
    module.r2.message,
  ]
}

output "main" {
  value = local.module_messages
}
```